# Slot (pointer to method member) as argument to method in SIP

Tags: c++, pyqt, qt5, signals-slots, python-sip

I have a C++ class defined with a method which has a sol (pointer to member method) as argument:

```
MyClass : public QDialog, private Ui::MyClassBase
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    MyClass( QWidget *parent = nullptr );

    void connectValueChanged( const QList<QWidget *> &widgets, void ( MyClass::*slot )() );
}
```

and

```
 void MyClass::connectValueChanged( const QList<QWidget *> &widgets, void ( MyClass::*slot )() )
 {
   Q_FOREACH ( QWidget *widget, widgets )
   {
     connect( w, &QWidget::signal, this, slot );
   }
 }
```

The `connectValueChanged` cannot be used as defined in the SIP file, I get a ***syntax error***.

---

I also tried to use `const char *slot` without success:
In the SIP file

```
void MyClass::connectValueChanged( const QList<QWidget *> &widgets, const char *slot);
```

I get an error (`no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::connectValueChanged`) as I suppose I need some `MethodCode` to achieve this.

---

Maybe some hints:

- [existing Qt method](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/sip/QtQml/qqmlproperty.sip#L79-L92)
  but using the old signal/slot connection.
- [SIP extension API](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/extension_api.html) either.
- `static QMetaObject::fromSignal` (returning a `QMetaObject`) [header](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobject.h#L171-L179) and [definition](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobject.cpp#L2129-L2143)

---

**What shall I do to define a method with a slot as argument in SIP ?**

I think this requires some `MethodCode` I am not capable to write at the moment.
I would like to use Qt5 new signal/slot connection (avoid using `const char *slot` in the cpp method, put possibly in the python method with some `MethodCode`)

Comment: What error do you get? How are you calling `connectValueChanged`?

Comment: I just updated the question with the error.

Comment: Can you show the actual piece of code where you call the function?

Comment: You're probably calling the function in the wrong way, check out my example and show what you're doing differently.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the pointer-to-member since I'm not sure whether this is supported at the moment. If you use the `const char*` signal/slot method, you also need to implement the methods like that otherwise you'll of course get a mismatch error.

```
class MyQObj : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MyQObj(QObject * parent = nullptr);

        void connectValueChanged(const QList<QObject*> &objects, const char * slot);

    public slots:
        void mySlot();
};

...

MyQObj::MyQObj(QObject * parent) : QObject(parent) {}

void MyQObj::connectValueChanged(const QList<QObject*> &objects, const char * slot) {
    for (auto p : objects)
        QObject::connect(p, SIGNAL(objectNameChanged(QString)), this, slot);
}

void MyQObj::mySlot() {
    std::cout << "Called slot\n";
}

...

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyQObj obj(&app);
    QObject xxx(&app);

    QList<QObject*> list;
    list.push_back(&xxx);
    obj.connectValueChanged(list, SLOT(mySlot()));

    QTimer::singleShot(1000, [&xxx](){
            xxx.setObjectName("newname");
    });

    return app.exec();
}
```

The SIP file could be something like:

```
%Module A

%Import QtCore/QtCoremod.sip

class MyQObj : public QObject
{
    public:
        MyQObj(QObject * parent /TransferThis/ = nullptr);

        void connectValueChanged(const QList<QObject*> &objects, const char* slot);

    public slots:
        void mySlot();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I could not correctly build this. If I keep the `using` line in the sip code I get an error (`sip: using is undefined`) and if I remove the line I get `unknown VoidSlot`. Am I missing something, could you drat the sip file too? Cheers.

Comment: I assumed you had access to c++11, I've changed the example with a `typedef` rather than a `using`.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I do have access to c++11. My intention is to use the new signal slot connection in Qt5, hence the pointer to member argument, which I would like to keep.

Comment: I am just wondering if it would not be possible to use some method code to transform the `const char *slot` to a pointer to method member. Cheers.

Comment: @DenisRouzaud I suppose that simply `sip` does not support pointers to members. Ideally, you could export the `const char*` version and use it to call the pointer to member method. You can convert from `const char*` to pointer member  with something like a `static const QHash<QString, void (MyQObj::*)()>` appropriately initialized.